# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Kinect.Tools

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kinect

I tried to create a simple console application which is using the Microsfot.Kinect.Tools. I add reference to the microsoft.Kinect.Tools.dll. I add the correspond namespace `using Microsoft.Kinect.Tools;`.  I am facing the following exception when I tried to check  if the import of the library is working:

> Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.Kinect.Tools" Version=
>   2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToker=..., or one of its dependencies. An attempt make to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

What I am trying to do is to create a function that records .xef files:

```
public void writeXefFiles(String filePath)
{
    using (KStudioClient client = KStudio.CreateClient())
    {
        client.ConnectToService();
       ...
    }    
}
```

However it seems that I cant call that function at all (the exception is rising).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

quite possible you have dll in your gac of some other version. Try uninstalling the same:

go to cmd and run the command: gacutil /u Microsoft.Kinect.Tools.dll

other reason could be the configuration: x86 or x64 or any cpu. Make sure you have used the correct configuration.

Comment: Yea the second one is my prob. I configure it to x64 architecture and now everything is working fine.

Comment: search for gacutil.exe in C:\Program FIles or C:\Program FIles (x86)